# Convert Git repos of without .git extention to gitolite repos having .git extension

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

I have one gitolite server and one old git server.
On my old git server I have about 80 repositories.
All are bare repos but don't have the .git extension.
I want to transfer all of them to new gitolite server so that if anyone in future need any old repo can access from running gitolite server without any issue and all repos will be at one place, which will be easy to manage.

I know I can clone repo from old git server and can push that repo to new gitolite server by making necessary repo entry in conf/gitolite-admin.conf file.

This is very much time consuming, I do want to copy all the repos at once from old git server to new gitolite server and perform necessary changes to conf/gitolite-admin.conf.

Is it possible to do so???

Answer (score 0):

> I do want to copy all the repos at once from old git server to new gitolite server and perform necessary changes to conf/gitolite-admin.conf.

Sure: see "[bringing existing repos into gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#existing)"

You can copy directly the bare repos to the gitolite server, in  `$HOME/repositories`.
Simply rename the folder, by adding a `.git` at the end.

Then:

- Run `gitolite setup` on the server
- declare them in `conf/gitolite-admin.conf`, commit and push the change from your local `gitolite-admin` clone.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all the repositories to your new server (assuming that you no longer need them on your old server). No need to `git clone`.

`tar cfz` all your repositories into one `.tar.gz` archive, copy it over via e.g. `scp` and extract the archive again on your new server.

If you want the repo names to be like `repository.git` rename them via `mv` before creating the archive file. This can easily be done with a little bash 'magic':

```
cd /path/to/your/repositories
for repo in *; do mv "$repo" "$repo.git"; done
```